# Which threadsafe JobRepository for multithreaded Step?

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch

While running spring batch job with partition, each of the slave threads are failing with the below error :

`[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] AbstractStep.execute(250) | Encountered an error saving batch meta data. This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted.
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=4623 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2 at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:185) at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:171)`

Job Repository being used is JobRepositoryFactoryBean. Spring batch version is 2.1.8 .
In `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table, for all steps the version is 2, even while running the steps for the first time.

Job Configuration as below:

```xml
<job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" parent="simpleJob">
    <step id="masterStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" parent="skipLimitStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="BulkPartitioner" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" />
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" parent="skipLimitStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="partitionPagingItemReader" writer="partitionItemWriter"   commit-interval="1"  processor="partitionitemProcessor" skip-limit="1000">
        </chunk>
        <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="BulkPartitioner" class="foo.bar.BulkPartitioner" scope="step"  >
    <property name="model" value="#{jobParameters['abc']}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="partitionPagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!--  <property name="fetchSize" value="#{jobParameters['fetch.size']}"></property>  -->
    <property name="fetchSize" value="1000"></property>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="select a, b, c" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="from d" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="where e= :f" /> 
            <property name="sortKey" value="e" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="f" value="#{stepExecutionContext[f]}" />  
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="1" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="foo.bar.mapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="simpleJob" 
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" abstract="true">
     <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="restartable" value="true"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="jobRepository" 
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="databaseType" value="oracle"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
    <property name="validateTransactionState" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

update: This is happening only for failed steps. successful completion of steps are updated correctly.

What could be the cause? TIA.

Comment: What database?  How is it configured?

Comment: updated post with job configuration. database used is Oracle 11g.

Comment: Is there a reason you're overriding the default transaction propagation?

Comment: when the job gets called from inside of another job, it should run in its own transaction. hence. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Spring Batch handles that for you with the defaults.  You shouldn't override it unless you want to do something out of the ordinary (which it doesn't look like you're doing here).

Comment: Tried with the default propagation. problem persists.

Comment: Is there only one `DataSource` being used here?  As in, is the batch schema tables in the same database as the business schema (it looks like it from above, but you've anonymized it a bit so I wanted to confirm)?

Comment: Yes, just one DataSource.batch + business tables are in same schema.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is a problem for others, this was the solution I found:

```
<property name="saveState" value="false" />
```

in the reader(s)/writer(s) for the concurrent job/step. As the logging mentions, "This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted" so you should consider:

```
<property name="restartable" value="false"/>
```

Sources:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator